# how to create a tablet background using android studio

Tags: android, background, tablet

I have been following this tutorial:
[Page](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-live-wallpaper-on-android-using-an-animated-gif--cms-23088).
I have been getting a lot of errors.
Can you please help me by sharing the code on `GitHub`?
You can also post your answer on `Stack Overflow`.
This is my [Gif](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-LYXjuDIbj6k/WU9kghlvNZI/AAAAAAAAAzY/ZOabSzHzFvYo321J8Gf1M2IqHJfKpOL5wCLcBGAs/s320/3690973e6a313f650e9fc1761e22e793.gif)
I have used this in my java file:

```
package com.example.background;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import java.io.IOException;


public class GIFWallpaperEngine extends WallpaperService{
private final int frameDuration = 20;

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Movie movie;
private boolean visible;
private Handler handler;

public GIFWallpaperEngine(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
    handler = new Handler();
}



public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    this.holder = surfaceHolder;
}

private Runnable drawGIF = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        draw();
    }
};

private void draw() {
    if (visible) {
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.save();
        // Adjust size and position so that
        // the image looks good on your screen
        canvas.scale(3f, 3f);
        movie.draw(canvas, -100, 0);
        canvas.restore();
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        movie.setTime((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % movie.duration()));

        handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
        handler.postDelayed(drawGIF, frameDuration);
    }
}
@Override
public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
    if (visible) {
        handler.post(drawGIF);
    } else {
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
}
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    try {
        Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(
                getResources().getAssets().open("wolverine.gif"));

        return new Engine(movie);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("GIF", "Could not load asset");
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Is there anything wrong because the override is showing an error.
It's this: Override is not required because method whatever super does.

Comment: First of things, you should your code 'cause and it was you trying, and show your `LogCat` error :)

Comment: Hello @franqobalsamo! I edited my code :)

Comment: Well, i 'd finished and i share with you the link in git. Now this is deprecated but happy code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the solution for me [GitLink](https://github.com/FrancoBalsamo/wallpaper)

Solution to your problem when you try to run app, first click in `app` and in `Edit Configurations`

[image]

Now, in `Launch Options` select **NOTHING**:

[image]

Last step, press `OK`:

[image]

Finally, you can run your app. Try it!

Comment: Hello @franqobalsamo, a new error is coming: Default Activity Not Specified

Comment: Hi! i'd updated code with images to you can understand how to you can run the service :) happy code!

Comment: Hello @franqobalsamo when I run it nothing happened

Comment: Yes, this is a service. If you look in your configurations in apps you can see your service. This is deprecated and it work in old versions android may be, you can try it with new codes or something

Comment: I'm using android 10